# permissions via the API

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive

Does anyone know if I can have a single one drive folder and then assign via the API different people, and then they would see only the folders that they are allowed to see.

I am trying to re-create the "views" functionality of dropbox enterprise

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the simplest way to do so is to use the Microsoft Graph API which has an entire set of endpoints that work with a OneDrive account.

The endpoints that will best serve you are the [Create Sharing Link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_createlink) and the [Add Permission](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_invite).

Note: Using the sharing link that doesn't require account authentication means anyone with that link can access the OneDrive folder/file that it is assigned to. If the user(s) have Microsoft Accounts or Microsoft Organizational Accounts (also known as work/school account) then the Add Permission endpoint is likely your best bet.